# What's a good tool/method to find which files on disk have been changed after a program has been run?

Tags: windows, file, replication, compare

I'm experiencing a strange issue where my Visual Studio 2005 C++ program crashes the first time it runs after a new build.  I'm having a difficult time debugging this intermittent issue and I suspect it's somehow related to a file somewhere on my hard drive that is being changed.  If I can find the file(s), that might provide some more insight into this issue.  Are there any good tools for observing which files are being created/deleted/modified when a specific program is run?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) tool. Set "Show File System Activity" to ON and set a filter on the process name to get only the traces you need.

Answer (score 0):

SysInternals (now Microsoft) FileMon

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [find](http://man.he.net/?topic=find&section=all).

```
touch ~/test-marker
# run your program
find <directory> -newer ~/test-marker
```

Comment: This isn't available in Windows, without some extra libraries. Based on the initial question, I think the target OS is Windows.

Comment: The question didn't specify base-install software only.